# how to calculate the number of bits required to address a word in direct mapped cache

Tags: caching, memory, assembly, memory-management, cpu-architecture

to get the offset I do the log2 of the number of bytes per data. then the index is the log2 of the total number of raws. What about the number of bytes for a word selection. How do you get those bits required for a word addressing/selection.

This is he  I have got [How does direct mapped cache work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15937002/how-does-direct-mapped-cache-work)

Wikipedia does not really talk about word selection since it talks about the cache being devided into 3 colunms, whiles with word selection we have 4 colunms.

> > Let us assume I have a frame of 16 words and a word is 64 bits. The address length is 32 bits. How do I calculate the number of bits required to address a byte within a word for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bit strange but one could just calculate it with simple math. just a simple triangular rule for example: for 64bits -> 32bits how will I have for 8 bits I am not sure if it is the right thing but it is working